# R How do I create a list with text from multiple txt files?

Tags: r, list, file, loops, path

I am trying to read through a list of n number of .txt files and save the content to a list of characters. However, when I read them and add them to the list "txts" it gives me the error:
"Read 32 items
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

Each of the txt files includes 32 rows of 32 characters ("0"s and "1"s). At first step I would like to get a list of n elements (each with 32 items with 32 characters each) with the content of the txt files.

I will need then to convert each of the 32x32 characters to a 1x1024 vector (I will use strstrip for that), and at the very end I will need to have a matrix of n (number of txts) rows and 1024 columns (number of characters of each txt file).

With the below I tried to create a list of the content of two txt files but gives me an error. I used scan because I need all characters in the txt files. I tried read.table and it works fine, but it converts them to numbers and I don't want that.

```
file_example <-list("digits/trainingDigits/0_0.txt","digits/trainingDigits/0_1.txt")

txts <- c()

for (i in file_example){
  nb = scan(s,what="character", sep=NULL)
  txts[s] <- c(nb)
}
```

Any ideas on how to solve it? I hope it's clear enough.

Thanks!!

---

Update:

I tried the below with the following code:

```
file_example <- c("digits/trainingDigits/0_0.txt","digits/trainingDigits/0_1.txt")

txts <- c()

mylist <- list()
for (i in 1: length(file_example)){
  nb = read.csv(file_example[[i]])
  txts[s] <- c(nb)
  txts <- as.character(nb$X)
  mylist[[i]] <- txts
}
```

However, what I get is a list of two elements, and within the 32 numbers, but the characters weren't kept I think.

first element of the list of two:

[[1]]
 [1] "1.111111e+19"         "1.111111111e+21"      "1.1111111111111e+24"  "1.1111110111111e+24"  "1.11111100000111e+25"
 [6] "1.11111100000001e+25" "1.11111100000001e+25" "1.111111e+25"         "1.111111e+25"         "1.11111e+25"
[11] "1.11111e+25"          "1.11111e+25"          "1.11111e+24"          "1.11111e+24"          "1.11111e+24"
[16] "1.11111e+24"          "1.111111e+25"         "1.111011e+25"         "1.111e+25"            "1.111e+24"
[21] "1.11100000000001e+24" "1.11100000000011e+24" "1.11100000000111e+24" "1.11000000111111e+23" "1.1110001111111e+23" 
[26] "1.1111111111111e+23"  "1.111111111111e+22"   "1.11111111111e+22"    "1.11111111e+21"       "1.1111e+20"
[31] "1.1e+19"

And the end goal is to get this for each of the .txt files, so then it can be converted to a vector with 1024 elements:

"[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  [64] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [127] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [190] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
 [253] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
 [316] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0
 [379] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0"

This will have 1024 characters

Thanks

Comment: We can set `colClasses=` in read.table to avoid converting input to numbers.

Comment: Please provide example text files.

Comment: Could you try something like `txts <- lapply(file_example, scan, what="character", sep=NULL)`?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you problem is to store each document as a list, and having numeric values as characther. As a matter of a fact, you can convert them back to characthers using `as.charachter()` 
Here I provide a simple example. If your data has more columns, just change the vector `txts` to matrix and put an extra for loop to store it indexing each row.

```
######### Creating the files
a<- c("0", "2","1","1")
b<- c("0","1","1","0")

#### path to read from and store the example
path<-"C:/Users/Carles/Desktop/"

write.csv(a,paste0(path,"a.txt"))
write.csv(b,paste0(path,"b.txt"))

# reading example
file_example<- c(paste0(path,"a.txt"), paste0(path,"b.txt"))

# creating a list to store values
mylist<-list()
for (i in 1:length(file_example)){
  nb = read.csv(file_example[i]) # reading the documents
  txts <- as.character(nb$x) # getting the vector x since read.csv stores data in dataset form
  mylist[[i]]<-txts # passing the texts stored to the list
}



> mylist
[[1]]
[1] 0 2 1 1

[[2]]
[1] 0 1 1 0
```

I hope it helps !
BR,

PD: For the next time, please, provide an example. It is important for the understanding of the problem better, as well as for being able to reproduce it.

Comment: Hi Carles
Thank you for the advise and your reply, it's my second time here.

Just to provide more information, the txt look like this when opened
0001
0110
0000
1110
For example, but with a higher amount of data (32x32 characters).

The output using your code is:
[[1]]
 [1] "1.111111e+19"         "1.111111111e+21"      "1.1111111111111e+24"  "1.1111110111111e....

And the end goal is to get this:

[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0...

Comment: You will need to provide part of your lists for me to understand it